# Is there a .Net FormatString for 1 to 2 decimal places?

Tags: .net, format-string

I have a requirement to format a given number to at least 1 decimal place and up to 2 decimal places as in:

```
4      -> 4.0
4.1    -> 4.1
4.25   -> 4.25
4.3333 -> 4.33
4.5    -> 4.5
5      -> 5.0
```

Is there a FormatString string which will deliver this?

as in:

```
MyDecimal.ToString("[something here]")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can conditionally include a second decimal place with the `#` format placeholder.

```
MyDecimal.ToString("0.0#")
```

Answer (score 1):

probably something like:

```
myDecimal.ToString("#.0#");
```

At least, based on the examples you gave hat'd work.

Answer (score 1):

The string `"0.0#"` should do that.

Answer (score 0):

Considering it in C#; it would be like below

```
//max. two decimal places
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4);         // "123.4"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.0);         // "123"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or to merge Anthony and Rahul's answers:

```
string.Format("{0:0.0#}", someNumber);
```

e.g.:

```
string formatStr = "{0:0.0#}";

var output = new StringBuilder();

var input = new List<double> { 4, 4.1, 4.25, 4.3333, 4.5, 5 };

foreach ( var num in input ) {
    output.AppendLine(num + " -> " + string.Format(formatStr, num));
}

/* output
4 -> 4.0
4.1 -> 4.1
4.25 -> 4.25
4.3333 -> 4.33
4.5 -> 4.5
5 -> 5.0
*/
```